# Получить файлы в папке (mp3), построить список с возможностью их воспроизводить

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Каким образом и инструментом можно сие выполнить, при изменении файлов(удалил, добавил новый) отражалось на странице?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустм, файлы лежат в папке **mp3**

```html
<?php
$dir = "mp3";
$files = scandir($dir);
echo "<ul>";
for($i = 2; $i < count($files); $i++)echo "<li onclick='playTrack(this.innerHTML)'>" . $files[$i] . "</li>";
echo "</ul>";
?>
<style>
li{
 cursor: pointer;
}
li:hover{
 background: gold;
}
</style>
<audio id=audio controls></audio>
<script>
function playTrack(name){
 audio.src = "mp3/" + name;
 audio.play();
}
</script>
```

Воспроизведение запускается кликом по соответствующему пункту списка.Прввда, код пока работает, если в именах файлов не всречаются русские буквы. Чтобы это урегулировать, понадобится дополнительные ра0бирательства с русскими кодировками и декодированием содержимого типа **decodeURIComponent**. Есть вариант использовать в именах файлов только латинские буквы, а для построения русскоязычного списка использовать метаданные файлов или сторонние данные из отдельного массива.